# How to set up I/O redirection in C with Xcode on a mac?

Tags: c, macos, io

I'm writing a program and I need to set the program up to get input from a text file and save the output in a text file. I'm using Xcode and I'm on a mac. I know I need to enter some redirection commands in the console but I'm not exactly sure how to do it. For example text files feel free to use input.txt and output.txt.

Thank you for the help.

Comment: Do you mean how to have Xcode execute your program providing IO redirection to stdin? Or are you only asking about how to redirect IO from a console prompt (which has nothing to do with Xcode, as it is a shell syntax thing) ?

Comment: Then that answer is below. Mr. Morris' has several options you can try.

Comment: Hi, I have another question about this. Do I type in 'command' into the console? If so, Do I just enter the file name or do I need the address of the file, i.e, users/name/desktop/file? Thanks

Comment: No. `command` is the name of your output program. Enjoy that, btw, as Xcode builds in the oddest paths with making binaries. you may want to edit the Project options and change where the binaries are written at link.

Comment: Do you know where Xcode saves the executable file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the terminal (command line) you can do

```
command < input.txt > output.txt
```

or

```
cat input.txt | command > output.txt
```

Edit:

```
Ok, thanks a lot. Just curious, when I type that in the terminal, 
how does it know to go to Xcode?
```

The only connection between running the command on the terminal and Xcode is that you build the program in Xcode.  That produces an executable that can be run either by Xcode or from the shell (terminal).  Running the program on the terminal has absolutely no effect on Xcode.

There might well be a way to redirect I/O from within Xcode (perhaps that is what you originally wanted) but I am unaware of it (don't use Xcode).

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot. Just curious, when I type that in the terminal, how does it know to go to Xcode?

Comment: Hi, I have another question about this. Do I type in 'command' into the console? If so, Do I just enter the file name or do I need the address of the file, i.e, users/name/desktop/file? Thanks.

Comment: You need to type the location of the command.  If you are in the directory containing the command (ie. the program you built), then do `./command` where `command` is the executable you built and `./` is the path to that command.  Alternatively, you can use the absolute path, eg /Users/you/path/to/command or a relative path. Changing to the directory containing the command is normal (using `cd`).

Comment: It goes by default in `~/Library/Developer/DerivedData/`, so for my test project called 'CodeReview' it is in `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CodeReview-dgcrwwdcmengjfbknfsrpfyppxoz//Build/Products/Debug/CodeReview`

Comment: See also: http://meandmark.com/blog/2011/04/xcode-4-finding-the-application-you-built/

Comment: Thanks William. I'll try to do it later today using your advice.

Comment: Got it! Basically, just drag the executable file from the products folder in your project into the terminal followed by '<' then enter the file you want input into the program. Thanks William.

Answer (score 1):

It seems difficult if not impossible to tell Xcode you wish to redirect standard input, output or error for your compiled command-line program. The Program > Scheme > Edit Scheme menu only helps out with application "Arguments Passes On Launch" [Cmd+<] which is something different than the redirection operators < and > in a shell. There seems no connection with a Terminal and Xcode, which also explains that your cannot debug a program launched from such external shell.

As a basic workaround without dependencies, several sites suggest you would bake this redirection into your program's code. This can even be done conditionally for Apple macOS like:

```
#ifdef __APPLE__
    freopen("input.txt", "r", stdin);
    freopen("output.txt", "w", stdout);
    freopen("error.txt", "w", stderr);
#endif
```

A slightly more elaborate example would leverage the "Environment Variables" as can be set on the very same Product Scheme tab and having program code like:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

#ifdef __APPLE__
        if (getenv("STDIN")) {
            if (!freopen(getenv("STDIN"), "r", stdin)) {
                NSLog(@"Unable to redirect stdin to '%s'\n", getenv("STDIN"));
            }
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Unknown environment variable STDIN so assuming stdin\n");
        }
        if (getenv("STDOUT")) {
            if (!freopen(getenv("STDOUT"), "w", stdout)) {
                NSLog(@"Unable to redirect stdout to '%s'\n", getenv("STDOUT"));
            }
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Unknown environment variable STDOUT so assuming stdout\n");
        }
#endif
```